# Storing a variable for a WordPress plugin without creating a new table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a custom theme which provides a way to change the layout of the homepage of a WordPress site. I want to give the user 3 options to choose between then based on that choice I'll style the homepage differently. I know how to have the user choose the layout, but I don't want to create a new table just to store this one piece of information. Is there another place I can store this variable for my theme? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) and [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) functions. Your key/value pair will be stored in the wp_options table.

Comment: Use update_option() to ensure that the value is create and updated. (Don't know if that option was available when this post was written)